# Szemerédi–Trotter theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

[Szemerédi–Trotter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%E2%80%93Trotter_theorem) theorem asserts that given $n$ points and $m$ lines in the plane, the number of incidences (i.e., the number of point-line pairs, such that the point lies on the line) is:

$O((mn)^{\frac{2}{3}}+m+n).$

I was wondering how many different proofs are known for this theorem? Is there any survey or references for these proofs? I know there are two proofs here https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~zdvir/papers/Dvir-survey.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I can think of at least three proofs:

1. [The original cell decomposition proof of Szemerédi-Trotter](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02579194)
2. [The proof via the Crossing Lemma given by Székely](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/erdos_dist/szekely.pdf)
3. [The proof using the polynomial ham sandwich theorem](http://yufeizhao.com/pm16/matousek-szt-poly.pdf)

[Adam Sheffer has an early draft of a book](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/ASheffer/000book.pdf) on incidence theory and the polynomial method, which mentions all three proofs.

Comment: The two proofs in Dvir's survey mentioned in the question appear to be (1) and (2) in this answer.

Comment: @j.c. Actually I think all three proofs are in Dvir's book: Cell Decomposition method is section 2.1.1, Crossing Lemma proof is section 2.1.2, and polynomial ham sandwich theorem is section 2.5.2.